# send JavaScript array through jQuery AJAX POST

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

What I want to do is send an JavaScript Array to a PHP file.
This is what I got:

```
var mydata = [];
        console.log(document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].name);
        for (var i = 0; i < document.getElementsByTagName('input').length; i++) {
            mydata[document.getElementsByTagName("input")[i].name] = document.getElementsByTagName("input")[i].value;
        };
        for (var i = 0; i < document.getElementsByTagName('select').length; i++) {
             mydata[document.getElementsByTagName("select")[i].name] = document.getElementsByTagName("select")[i].value;
        };
        console.log(mydata);

        $.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            url: "q.php",
            data: {'lol': JSON.stringify(mydata)},
            contentType: 'application/json',
            dataType: 'json'
        })
        .done(function( msg ) {
            alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
            $('#debug').html(msg);
        });
```

So as you can see, I create an array with a loop, at that moment all is fine. The problem is when I try to sent it through POST with JSON. I don't know if this is the best method...

I tried without `JSON.stringify();` but the `$_POST` still empty

It seems like the post isn't sent, but I can see in the console the XHR post request  has been sent.

Comment: You said: "but the same error occurs".  What is the error?  Can you provide the error message?

Comment: The POST that you see contains the data that you need? I think that the JSON.stringify is not necessary. you are getting a response error or a javascript error?

Comment: **EDIT** The $_POST is empty, I tried with out the JSON.stringify but it still empty.

Comment: Edit your question with what the `mydata` variable contains

Comment: Ok @Bankzilla. Give me a moment

Comment: You can try without this line:  `contentType: 'application/json',`

Comment: @Bankzilla >> [wlicence: "A1S2S-D3D4F-4G5H5-H6J67-K8K8L", snumber: "ABCDEFGHIJK", ram: "4", hd: "160", brand: "1"] This is what appears in the console when I do a console.log to mydata

Comment: Same thing with that @Tareq you got another idea?

Answer (score 3):

Try to use this code and see the changes.

remove the 

`contentType: 'application/json',
dataType: 'json'`

And change `var mydata = []` into `var mydata = {}`

your ajax should look like this

```
        $.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            url: "q.php",
            data: {'lol': mydata}
        })
        .done(function( msg ) {
            alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
            $('#debug').html(msg);
        });
```

You dont have to stringify your mydata because you already decleared it as object.

Hope it helps